# Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Not Found when deleting event

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have below method to delete event in calendar:

```c#
public async Task<string> DeleteEventInCalendarAsync(TokenResponse token, string googleUserId, string calendarId, string eventId)
{
            string result = null;

            try
            {
                if (_calService == null)
                {
                    _calService = GetCalService(token, googleUserId);
                }

                // Check if event exist
                var eventResource = new EventsResource(_calService);
                var erListRequest = eventResource.List(calendarId);
                var eventsResponse = await erListRequest.ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                var existingEvent = eventsResponse.Items.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == eventId);

                if (existingEvent != null)
                {
                    var deleteRequest = new EventsResource.DeleteRequest(_calService, calendarId, eventId);
                    result = await deleteRequest.ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                result = null;
                _logService.LogException(exc);
            }

            return result;
}
```

And I am getting error as follow -

```
Google.GoogleApiException Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Not Found [404] Errors [ Message[Not Found] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global] ]
```

Can you help me understand why this error? Or where I can find the details about these error?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is due to the event's id you are passing doesn't exist or you are passing it in the wrong way. Following the [.Net Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet) I made a simple code example on how to pass the event's id to the ***Delete(string calendarId, string eventId)*** method from the ***Class Events***

```c#
namespace CalendarQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define  request.
            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
            // List events.
            Events events = request.Execute();
            Event existingEvent = events.Items.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == "your event id you want to get");
            Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
            if (existingEvent != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", existingEvent.Summary, existingEvent.Id);
                string deleteEvent = service.Events.Delete("primary",  existingEvent.Id).Execute();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

### Notice

I made this example in a synchronous syntax way for testing purposes in the console. After you test it and see how it works, you could adapt it to your code. Remember, make your you are passing the correct ***Id***.

### Docs

For more info check this doc:

- [Namespace Google.Apis.Calendar.v3](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/latest/api/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.html)